# How to open Play Store URL on button click in Angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to open Play Store url with the help of Play Store app when clicking on button. I have many app urls from Play Store.

**For Eg:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninjakiwi.bftg

App's page should not open in the browser. It has to open in official Google Play Store app when clicking on button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use app store link provided by Google.
Ex:

**market://details?id=**

This way choose option will not come and directly open in playstore.
Here id = your playstore appID ex: com.ninjakiwi.bftg (In your case)

> **market://**    Launches the Play Store app to load the target page.
>
> **http://**    Lets the user choose whether to launch the Play Store app
> or the browser to handle the request. If the browser handles the
> request, it loads the target page on the Google Play website.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html

Okay. window.location.href will not work here. So here is the complete solution for you:

You will have to use **utils/utils module** provided by Nativescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import * as utils from "utils/utils";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-details",
    templateUrl: "./item-detail.component.html",
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    openURL() {
        utils.openUrl("market://details?id=com.ninjakiwi.bftg");
    }
}
```

**Here openURL function will be called on button Tap event from view.**
More:
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils

Comment: Intent wont work in nativescript.then how can I link into that url

Comment: Redirect your page to  market://details?id=com.ninjakiwi.bftg  instead of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninjakiwi.bftg after button click

Comment: I'm getting no provider for location issue. Please check this : https://paste.ofcode.org/gSXXKpruPLFKMbUGpJW6j9

Comment: @Stephen have a look now. I have added complete solution for you. Enjoy :)